# MVC pass ICollection from controller to view and back to controller without displaying it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I have a `public string name {get;set;}` in my model, and I want to pass it from my controller, to a view and then back to a controller (in an List -> Edit -> Save type of example) but *do not* want to show it in the view, then I just have an `@Html.HiddenFor...` field and it will get passed with the model back to the `Save` action on my controller. I understand that.

What if I have the same situation with a list of things. For instance a `public virtual ICollection<Contact> Friends {get;set;}` that then I want to pass from the controller to a view **not show it** but have it persist and get passed back to a controller?

Thanks

Comment: What do you do with the list collection of Contacts?

Comment: Ideally, I would bring the ICollection to the view, show it as a html multiselect and then bring it back to the controller. With what I have I can only bring the multiselect back to the controller separately and not as part of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your use case, it would be wasteful to render the entire `Friends` object and POST is back to your controller. You could cache the object (in your session, for example if it's short lived) and have the multi-select just POST the IDs for your contacts.

Comment: that's true. I should handle just the ids. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize it to a JSON string and then pass it back with the `@Html.HiddenFor` helper. Inside the `Save` action I would then deserialize it back to a `ICollection<Contact>`.

For example:

```
string friends = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Friends);
```

Save action:

```
var friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Contacts>>(myReturnData);
```

Comment: oh, duh. great answer! I will give that a shot!